# What mechanics control the path emblems on the player cards?

Tags: fire-emblem-fates

In *Fire Emblem Fates*, when you view a player card, it displays the three emblems of each path. I have seen them in numerous different states, but I cannot find anything online which explains exactly how they work. I imagine that when they are lit up (as with Birthright and Conquest below), it signifies the player has completed that path, but I am fairly certain I have seen it highlighted in different colors than the one shown. Also, how is the completion status associated between files? If I start a new game after beating one path, will my file still reflect that or must I use the *Branch of Fates* option on the main menu? In short, **what are the mechanics that control and influence the emblems on the player card for each path?**

[image: Fire Emblem Fates Emblems]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you guessed the emblems light up to signal the player has completed a path. The different colors indicate which difficulty the path was played on. I believe it is bronze for normal, silver for hard, and gold for expert. You can tap on the emblem to see which difficulty it represents.

As for associating the save between files, it does not matter if you start a new game completely or use the branch fates option. The game simply looks for path data on your SD card. If you only purchased one physical path and the other two as DLC, or you purchased the special edition you will have no problems. However, if you purchased both Birthright and Conquest as physical copies make sure to put your saves in the "extra" save slots to ensure they are saved to the SD card instead of the game cartridge.